# PhpStorm FTP connectivity slow and doesn't retrieve anything

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, remote-server

I recently downloaded the new PhpStorm 9.0.2 and for some reason I'm unable to start working on a project with remote server.

When setting up the remote server, the connectivity check takes 58 seconds and returns ok status (so it doesn't fail), while my winSCP connects to my server within under a second. The next thing is that the program loads for another 60 seconds but doesn't retrieve the directories list and I can't choose a root directory for my project.

I tried Google, but the issue doesn't seem to be a widely reported one.

Computer is a brand new ThinkPad running Windows 7 64-bit

I'm very thankful for all help.

Alari

Comment: Try switching between Active and passive FTP modes -- any difference?

Comment: Yes, that made a world of difference and once again all is right with the world, thank you very much!
I am however very curious as to why this little change made such a difference and why active wouldn't work?

Comment: Could be: 1) your firewall 2) firewall on server which does not allow active connections (not properly configured?) 3) FTP server configuration. Your another FTP program most likely configured to use passive connections by default or is very clever in detecting that active connection will not work (e.g. remembers previous connections results etc)